# How do I legally set up an exchange?

Tags: exchanges, legal

I'm asking about legal concerns, not technological ones. If I'm based in the USA, should the exchange be a US company? If not, where should it be based?

How is banking set up?

Comment: I think national governments will never accept bitcoins. I am all for bitcoins and all against national governments. If you want to venture into bitcoins, prepare to leave everything behind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because now it's off topic under the current site scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think StackExchange is the best place to ask for legal advice.

Logically, one would set up a company, get a business bank account and start their operations. However, it is very advisable to consult a lawyer first, as there are some legal concerns one should keep in mind, like [the money laundering regulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering#United_States) that one should adhere to.